# Why my Android studio application stop debugging

Tags: android

I don't know why but when I debug my app on Android studio my app stop debugging as the picture and the problem is when I generate thé apk file my app works fine.[image: d]

Comment: Seems to be an issue wid your mobile device or your usb cable or the emulator

Comment: IT can debug other projects